# Parsing X509 DSS Certificate to get P, Q, G and Y

Tags: java, parsing, cryptography, x509

I am trying to parse a X509 Certificate that contains a Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA) public key.

Using the javax.security.cert.X509Certificate class and getPublicKey() method I've been able to get P, Q, G and Y:

```
P: 0279b05d bd36b49a 6c6bfb2d 2e43da26 052ee59d f7b5ff38 f8288907 2f2a5d8e 2acad76e ec8c343e eb96edee 11
Q: 036de1
G: 03 
Y: 02790a25 22838207 4fa06715 1def9df5 474b5d84 a28b2b9b 360a7fc9 086fb2c6 9aab148f e8372ab8 66705884 6d
```

However, I'm not sure what format this is and how to parse it to convert it to long\BigInteger in Java.

Does anybody know how to do this conversion?

I am currently assuming it is Hex and I am parsing it as so - but I'm not 100% sure if this is correct.

Comment: Homework? These parameters are so extremely weak that someone must have chosen them deliberately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *already* have the big integers. Here is how it goes for me:

```
X509Certificate xc = X509Certificate.getInstance(ecert);
PublicKey pkey = xc.getPublicKey();
DSAPublicKey dk = (DSAPublicKey)pkey;
DSAParams pp = dk.getParams();
System.out.printf("p = 0x%X\n", pp.getP());
System.out.printf("q = 0x%X\n", pp.getQ());
System.out.printf("g = 0x%X\n", pp.getG());
System.out.printf("y = 0x%X\n", dk.getY());
```

assuming the encoded certificate is in `ecert`. Interfaces `DSAPublicKey` and `DSAParams` are in `java.security.interfaces`.

You can also go through a `KeyFactory` and use the `getKeySpec()` method to export the public key as a `DSAPublicKeySpec`, which will offer the same values as `BigInteger` instances. I am not sure if there is a gain to go through that road, though.

What you show is probably some kind of encoding, but I am quite at a loss to know which one. Anyway, the 'Q' parameter shall be at least 160-bit wide in a proper DSA public key.